# Gamepad in GNU/Linux, continuous button press

Tags: linux, gaming, slackware

I have two Playstation 3 gamepads connected to my Slackware based system. Everything works as it should, I have two devices as /dev/input/js*, which I can cat and see data coming from. I can also play games in MAME.

However, the problem is that when I press and hold a button, it doesn't register continuously, only in bursts. Hence a game that requires the user to press and hold a button to perform some feature, do not work. This works perfectly fine with a keyboard, however.

Is there some configuration options(s) I can tweak to make this register properly?